# Align content to bottom when using flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this basic layout with a static header and footer, pushed to the top and bottom respectively. The content section in the middle fills the space, and there's a scrollbar for this section in case the content is too large for it to fit.

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="header">
    Header
  </div>

  <div id="middle">
    Middle content
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}

#middle {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gsztcLum/).

I want the content of this middle section to start from the bottom, and not the top, while keeping the overflow scrollbars in case the content is too big, but I can't seem to figure out how.

I've tried setting margins to 0 and read about flex-direction, but none of those seem to work.

Comment: Your `#middle`still has `display: block`, you need to add `display: flex`, so that `align-items: flex-end;` can start having an effect. (FYI, Chrome dev tools showed a `(!)` next to that property, with a tooltip saying this already.)

Comment: That removes the scrolling functionality unfortunately. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0eykLq9b/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Consider editing your question to use a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/5351721) which is essentially StackOverflow's built-in version of jsfiddle. It makes it easy for folks to run your code without leaving the page, and copy your code to their answers where they can edit it as a new StackSnippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

```
  <div id="header">
    Header
  </div>

  <div id="middle" class="content-end">
    Middle content
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Please add this in your css:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}

#middle {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 
  display: flex;
}

.content-end
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start; 


}
```

[image: scroll]

Comment: That removes the scrolling functionality unfortunately: https://jsfiddle.net/0eykLq9b/1/

Comment: let me edit the solution , I forgot to remove one thing.

Comment: @NicknameGenerator please try it now using the above code

Comment: @RafiaZafar This would be a great opportunity to use a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/5351721).

Comment: I'll try, Thanks @Sean

Answer (score 0):

Please update your css there are not major changes. Use proper `HTML` tags in `#middle`

```
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; margin: 0;
}
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
#middle {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: calc(100vh - 180px);
}
#middle * {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

With this approach the first child in `#middle` will start from the bottom and rest will follow it. you can play around with this `padding-top`.